# Cast datetime in the where clause of the query

Tags: sql, date, datetime, casting, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT *
FROM tblClassAppointments
INNER JOIN tblClassGroups ON tblClassAppointments.GroupID = tblClassGroups.GroupID
WHERE (
        ('2015-07-13' >= StartTime)
        AND ('2015-07-13' <= EndTime)
        AND ('2015-07-13' > StartTime)
        AND ('2015-07-13' >= EndTime)
        )
    OR (
        ('2015-07-13' >= StartTime)
        AND ('2015-07-13' < EndTime)
        AND ('2015-07-13' > StartTime)
        AND ('2015-07-13' <= EndTime)
        )
    OR (
        ('2015-07-13' <= StartTime)
        AND ('2015-07-13' < EndTime)
        AND ('2015-07-13' >= StartTime)
        AND ('2015-07-13' <= EndTime)
        )
    OR (
        ('2015-07-13' <= StartTime)
        AND ('2015-07-13' >= EndTime)
        )
```

I use above query for getting class appointments which are placed for a  certain time period. I need to cast the `StartTime(tblClassAppointments.StartTime)` and `EndTime(tblClassAppointments.EndTime)` as `yyyy-mm-dd`.

**What I tried :**

I tried

```
 CONVERT(char(10), StartTime, 126)
```

and

```
CONVERT(char(10), EndTime, 126)
```

instead of `StartTime` and `EndTime.` It gave an error.

**What I need :**

How I convert `StartTime` and `EndTime` as `yyyy-mm-dd` inside the where clause itself? (both the fields are in type of datetime)

Please advice me. Thanks

Comment: What was the error you received?

Comment: "It gave an error." Please ALWAYS add the error message if you got one. "It gave an error" as the only statement is absolutely useless.

Comment: I'm sorry, I understand my weak point. I am trying to get that error message back. I will post it. Thanks for pointing out my mistakes.

Comment: Your date expressions should be fine.  Unless you have rather arcane internationalization settings, SQL Server understands YYYY-MM-DD format for dates.  Your query can probably be radically simplified, but you don't give sample data, desired results, and a clear statement of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I understand the mistakes in my question. I will improve that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your WHERE clause is too confusing, I don't understand it at all, I would try using BETWEEN when possible.

I am willing to bet you are getting a truncation error, because you are trying to convert a datetime datatype to a `char(10)`, which is way too small.  If all you care about is the date portion, then cast/convert to DATE datatype.

Here is an example of one way to do this:

```
; with CTE1 as (
    SELECT *
    , cast(StartTime as date) as StartTime2
    , cast(EndTime as date) as EndTime2
    FROM tblClassAppointments
    INNER JOIN tblClassGroups ON tblClassAppointments.GroupID = tblClassGroups.GroupID
)
select *
from CTE1
WHERE
    ('2015-07-13' between StartTime2 and EndTime2)
OR (
    ('2015-07-13' <= StartTime2)
    AND ('2015-07-13' < EndTime2)
    AND ('2015-07-13' >= StartTime2)
    AND ('2015-07-13' <= EndTime2)
    )
OR (
    ('2015-07-13' <= StartTime2)
    AND ('2015-07-13' >= EndTime2)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment and doesn't directly address any formatting issue with strings.  Your date comparisons are just complicated.  If `StartTime` and `EndTime` have a time component, and you want to know if the *entire* day of '2015-07-13' is covered, then use:

```
WHERE StartTime <= '2015-07-13' and EndTime >= '2015-07-14'
```

That is, the period starts before the day begins and ends after the day starts.

If you want to know if *any part* of the date is covered:

```
WHERE StartTime < '2015-07-14' and EndTime >= '2015-07-13'
```

That is, the period starts before the day ends and begins after the day starts.

If you don't like '2015-07-14' in the logic, then use `DATEADD(day, 1, '2015-07-13')`.

And, if you want to be independent of internationalization settings, you can also use `CAST('20150714' as DATE)`.